# Testcafe not working for Nuxt/Vue Amplify/Cognito calls. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, e2e-testing, aws-amplify, testcafe

I have been trying out Testcafe for our Nuxt application E2E tests as I understood it has good selectors with VueJS and its working great except for the parts where a call is made to cognito via amplify for user login/signup. It might be a testcafe and amplify issue rather than the frontend framework issue as the Login/Signup works absolutely fine. Also tried replacing the Cognito calls with normal REST api calls and it works fine too. Also tried it with Cypress and they work fine but Testcafe has better coverage in terms of cross browser testing so maybe a better option. Do you know if how I can fix this error or its better to look into different frameworks? Will try to share share my code in the best way possible as I cannot share my repo as its for my company. And will be happy to answer with more code or clarifications if required. Thanks and find the code below:

My submit function:

```
    async submit() {
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (this.$v.$invalid) return;
      this.disabled = true;
      try {
        await this.registerUser({
          username: this.email,
          password: this.newPassword,
          attributes: {
            given_name: this.firstname,
            family_name: this.lastname,
            email: this.email,
            'custom:isPerson': 'true',
            'custom:dataPrivacy': 'true'
          }
        });
        this.$router.push(this.appendLocalization('/user/confirmuser'));
        this.disabled = false;
      } catch (error) {
        this.$log.error('Could not register user', error);
        this.disabled = false;
      }
```

The amplify function:

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    userPoolId: process.env.userPoolId,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.userPoolWebClientId,
    region: process.env.region
  }
});

export const state = () => {
  return {
    session: {},
    user: {}
  };
};

export const mutations = {
  setUser: (state, user) => {
    state.user = { ...user };
    state.session = state.user.signInUserSession;
  }
};

registerUser: ({ commit }, credentials) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Auth.signUp({
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        attributes: credentials.attributes
      })
        .then((user) => {
          commit('setUser', user);

          resolve(user);
        })
        .catch(reject);
    }),
```

My Testcafe code:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
fixture`Signup Page`.page`http://localhost:3000/de/user/signup`;

const email = Selector('input').withAttribute('name', 'email');
const password = Selector('input').withAttribute('name', 'password');
const checkbox = Selector('input').withAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
const button = Selector('button').withAttribute('name', 'submit');
const getLocation = ClientFunction(() => document.location.href);

test('Test successful signup', async (t) => {
  const validemail =
    'WebFunctionalTest' + new Date().getTime() + '@something.com';
  const validpassword = 'password';
  await t
    .typeText(email, validemail)
    .typeText(password, validpassword)
  await t.click(button).debug();
  await t.expect(getLocation()).contains('userconfirm');
});
```

Signup Error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at c (hammerhead.js:16)
    at i (hammerhead.js:16)
    at value (hammerhead.js:6)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
    at _traverse (commons.app.js:12575)
```

P.S: I can see that Testcafe is making the cognito call and is getting a proper response in network tab but somehow not handling it in the code. I thought Testcafe should behave like a normal user testing like click the button and wait for the whole sequence to finish i.e successful page transition but somehow it's not.

I have spent quite sometime trying to figure this out but couldnt so posting it elaborately here, any help will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We appreciate your efforts but unfortunately this information is not sufficient to give a precise answer. TestCafe team would really appreciate it if you share a working example with us. Since you cannot share it in public you can send it at support@devexpress.com

Comment: If you can share some public url of your project to us please take into account the following:

our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If you want us to further research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us support@devexpress.com or post it here) a written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: Ok thanks will talk about it with my Manager and get back to you. Thanks for the reply.